# HubSpot live chat imbedding in Next.js 13 with typescript

Tags: next.js, chat, hubspot

In my application when the chat box is working fine for when I refresh the button but when I navigate through the other pages and come back to the imbedded page the chatbox is not appearing. I want to integrate HubSpot chat in my "Help" page only on this page user should a chat window.
this is my code
`your text`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Lij.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add Hubspot chat to Next.js 13 with app router and typescript:

```
import Script from 'next/script'
 
export default function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <section>{children}</section>
      <Script
    type="text/javascript"
    id="hs-script-loader"
    async
    defer
    src="//js.hs-scripts.com/HUBSPOT_SCRIPT_ID.js"
  />
    </>
  )
}
```

Check out the [Next.js documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts).